# Where does xmlns:tns come from when using schemagen

Tags: xsd, jaxb, schemagen, annotated-pojos

We are using [schemagen](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.0.2/docs/schemagenTask.html) to create an XSD from some annotated POJOs.

Here is our ant target

```
<target name="generate-xsd" depends="compile">
    <taskdef name="schemagen" classname="com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenTask" 
                     classpathref="xjc.classpath"/>
    <schemagen srcdir="src" destdir="generated" includeantruntime="false">
        <include name="com/acme/exam/delivery/records/**"/>
        <schema namespace="http://www.acme.com/deliverylog" 
                            file="deliverylog.xsd"/>
        <schema namespace="" file="supplemental.xsd"/> 
    </schemagen>
</target>
```

This is generating

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.acme.com/deliverylog" 
           xmlns:tns="http://www.acme.com/deliverylog" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

**Where does the tns namespace come from and what does it signify?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That infomration comes from the package level annotation `@XmlSchema` which can be found in the `package-info` class.  See below for an example.

**package-info**

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.acme.com/deliverylo",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**Sample XML**

`elementFormDefault` specifies which elements should be namespace qualified (true = all, false = only global elements), and `targetNamespace` defines what the namespace is.

```
<foo xmlns="http://www.acme.com/deliverylog">
    <bar>Hello World</bar>
</foo>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html